# in page "http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup"

Tags: ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i type "ssh hal" and i get "ssh: Could not resolve hostname hal: Name or service not known"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229588/in-page-%22http://wiki.ros.org/ros/networksetup%22/) by [G strat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26332/g-strat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just an example how you can debug the network setup.

Directly below the line with the `ssh hal` and `ping marvin`, it says you should check the section `Name Resolution` on this page.

Do you have two computers with the following network configuration (hostname/IP)?

> marvin.example.com : 192.168.1.1

> hal.example.com : 192.168.1.2

If not, this is clear. You need to properly configure your computers to follow this example as it is on the page....

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1